# How can I improve my INSERT statement for Security

Tags: php, sql

First up, my code: (I am using PDO as I was told it's more secure)

```
<?php
    // Dan - PDO Connection and Insert
    $servername = "REMOVED";
    $username = "REMOVED";
    $password = "REMOVED";
    $dbname = "REMOVED";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        // Set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $FirstName = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['FirstName'])));
        $LastName = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['LastName'])));
        $Company = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Company'])));
        $Email = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Email'])));
        $Telephone = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Telephone'])));
        $Subject = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Subject'])));
        $Message = trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Message'])));

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contact_form (FirstName, LastName, Company, Email, Telephone, Subject, Message) 
        VALUES (:FirstName, :LastName, :Company, :Email, :Telephone, :Subject, :Message)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':FirstName', $FirstName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':LastName', $LastName);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Company', $Company);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Email', $Email);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Telephone', $Telephone);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Subject', $Subject);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Message', $Message);

        // Use exec() because no results are returned
        $stmt->execute();

        $to = "REMOVED";
        $subject = "Contact Us";
        $message = "First Name: ". $_POST['FirstName'] ."
        \nLast Name: ". $_POST['LastName'] ."
        \nCompany: ". $_POST['Company'] ."
        \nEmail Address: ". $_POST['Email'] ."
        \nTelephone: ". $_POST['Telephone'] ."
        \nSubject: ". $_POST['Subject'] ."
        \nComments: ". $_POST['Message'] ."";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        header('Location: thank-you.php');
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;
?>
```

Is this statement already secure? I was told passing the variables into the query direct is bad practice and can be a way in for injection etc?

How can I make this query safe/injection free or at least minimise any risk.

Comment: [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) are required to make full use out of PDO statements. Ill post a quick example in a few minutes when I'm back on my pc

Comment: Thank you so much @Crecket. I knew I was doing something wrong. I have been using MySQLi and then inserting like the example above but was told changing over to PDO and using Prepared Statements is important. I can't get my head around them. :(

Comment: I think I may have cracked it. Can you check my updated code?

Comment: you don't need `trim(addslashes(htmlspecialchars` if you use prepared statements. also, `bindParam` does not need the `:`.

Comment: Just posted it as a answer aswell with my own version but you got it

Comment: I've marked your reply as the answer @Cracket. Thank you so much all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic synthax is the following for BindValue:

1. First enter the target (E.G. :FirstName)
2. Enter the variable (You
   can not enter plain text, variables are mandatory here);
3. Optional:
   PARAM_STR and PARAM_INT are the most common. For this, if the input
   isn't the type that you enter it will cancel the query
4. Optional:
   Max character length

So this would be it for your code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contact_form (FirstName, LastName, Company, Email, Telephone, Subject, Message) 
VALUES (:Firstname, :LastName, :Company, :Email, :Telephone, :Subject, :Message)";
$new_statement = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$new_statement->bindValue(':Firstname', $FirstName, PDO::PARAAM_STR, 100);
$new_statement->bindValue(':LastName', $LastName);
$new_statement->bindValue(':Company', $Company);
$new_statement->bindValue(':Email', $Email);
$new_statement->bindValue(':Telephone', $Telephone);
$new_statement->bindValue(':Subject', $Subject);
$new_statement->bindValue(':Message', $Message);
$new_statement->execute();
```

Don't but qoutes around the targets btw (All you have to put in the query is :target and not ':target'), this is taken care of automatically

Comment: you can also use '`?'` (positional) You didn't mention that, Also you can use `bindParam()` or use it inside `execute()`.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for the advice provided above, it's a great help and I now have the joy of replacing my vulnerable statements with PDO lol.